# Which mean to calculate for a series of points (x,y)?

Tags: means

I have a series of points in space with $(x_i,y_i)$ coordinates. And I would like to represent the average/mean point of this series:

--> Should I go for an arithmetic or a geometric mean of $x$ and $y$ coordinates  ?

Thanks a lot to answer to my naive question :)

Comment: What do you need the mean for? The answer to this question might make this question answerable.

Comment: To center a standard deviational ellipse: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/GP_ToolRef/spatial_statistics_tools/how_directional_distribution_colon_standard_deviational_ellipse_spatial_statistics_works.htm   ...From this website I would say it's a geometric mean...

Comment: I don't know the answer, but why don't you try both and see which works best?

Comment: I computed both, and they are very close... that's why I am asking :-) !

Comment: Standard deviation is always computed using the *arithmetic* mean.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the situation. e.g the center of mass in case of uniform mass density $\rho$ would be
$$
(X,Y) 
= 
\left(
\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^n \rho \cdot X_i }{\sum_{i=1}^n \rho}, \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^n \rho \cdot Y_i }{\sum_{i=1}^n \rho}
\right)
=
\left(
\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^n \cdot X_i }{n}, \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i }{n}
\right)
= (\bar{X}, \bar{Y})
$$
where the bar designates the arithmetic mean.

For other problems the geometric or harmonic mean (exists, if all values are positve) might be more useful.

All three are related:
$$
\bar{x}_H \le \bar{x}_G \le \bar{x}_A
$$